# usage of regrettably/unfortunately

Tags: difference

Regrettably/Unfortunately he didn't come to the class.

Which one is more strong? Is there some differences between the meaning of the above sentences?

Comment: None of your options express good or bad behaviour and it's general that absent from class is not good behaviour, But if there are any conditions or situation then you can't say, it's bad behaviour.

Comment: _Unfortunately_ implies that it was simply bad luck (fortune) that he was absent on a particular occasion. _Regrettably_, that his decision not to come is something to be regretted (by him or others).